# Overriding SASS variables in Vue component from parent

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

In a Vue component, you can define scoped SASS variables. Is it somehow possible to override them from the parent, such that you could customize the look of the component based on where you use it? I have tried using deep selectors and !default values, but with no success. Making the styles non-scoped is not an option.

Example, trying to change the child's color to black from parent:

```scss
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.child-component::v-deep {
  $color: #000;
}
</style>
```

Child:

```scss
<style lang="scss" scoped>
$color: #fff;

.text {
  color: $color;
}
</style>
```

Comment: When a scoped CSS is "processed" those class names get converted to match the element's transpiled class names  


While your CSS variable method work, It feels very hack-y to me, I think your best bet will be using props to pass some sort of "style" to the child and changing classes accordingly

Comment: @UdithIshara fair point, it feels hacky to me as well, and I've been using props for style before. However, that felt even hack-ier: the problem comes when you want to pass a SASS variable as a prop to use in styling, as those are not parsed correctly. I also prefer to keep as much style in CSS as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The current workaround I've found is to pass the value through regular CSS variables.

Parent:

```scss
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.child-component {
  --color: #000;
}
</style>
```

Child:

```scss
<style lang="scss" scoped>
$color: var(--color, #fff);

.text {
  color: $color;
}
</style>
```